# retrieve password from Thunderbird 17

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using T-bird 17.0.8. I need to retrieve the password Thunderbird is using to
 connect to my email account because I have forgotten it. [This](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=678215) link seems to 
explain the solution, but that's for an older version of Thunderbird and I can't find 
the 'option' link in the 'Tools' menu no more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll find it under Edit -> Preferences -> Security -> Passwords -> Saved Passwords -> Show Passwords. Click Yes at the prompt to show the passwords.

Comment: OK: It's called 'Preferences', not 'Options'...

Comment: I am translating from norwegian, so I'm not 100% sure if it's called Options. It should be all the way on the bottom of the Edit menu.

Comment: You can run an application in English from command line by specifying the `LANG` variable. E.g.: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 thunderbird`

Answer (score 1):

The given menu path is probably valid for Thunderbird on Windows. There, the menu item for accessing the settings / options dialog is traditionally in the "Tools" menu. On Linux, this menu item is traditionally in the "Edit" menu. Don't ask me why, if I remember correctly this convention reaches back to the late 90s at least.

So just open Thunderbird's settings dialog, wherever the menu item may be found ;) From there, you can go as described in mozillaZine's forum.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04
Thunderbird 60.6.1 (32-bit)

Very top menu bar on desktop -
Edit > Preferences

Pop-up appears - with Security (padlock icon) highlighted.  In same dialog box, click "Saved Passwords" - righthand side, about a quarter of the way down
"Saved logins" pop-up should appear.
Lower righthand corner - click "Show Passwords"
Dialog box should appear as pop-up - "Are you sure you wish to show your passwords?"

Above instructions tested 11 September 2019

Comment: Correction - Instructions tested 1 September 2019  - not 11 September 2019 (JH)