# Which file on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS contains Skype credentials?

Tags: 12.04, skype

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS. I've also installed Skype 4.3 for Linux on my machine. But I've forgotten my credentials. If I could get my credentials(i.e. my Skype Username and Password) from some file or by using some command it would be better for me. 
Is there any command or any file from which I can get it?
Can someone please help me in this regard please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask 1 question at a time. Thunderbird has been asked before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/347013/retrieve-password-from-thunderbird-17

Answer (score 1):

It should be in

```
/home/$USER/.Skype/{SKYPE_USER}/config.xml
```

So you can easily find out your user name. The password is encrypted using AES-256 so you will need to contact skype or use a password reset tool from them.

[Source: see page 67](http://recon.cx/en/f/vskype-part2.pdf)

---

Thunderbird see [retrieve password from Thunderbird 17](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347013/retrieve-password-from-thunderbird-17)

Comment: Do I need to type this on command prompt?

Comment: It is a directory so not a command. You can use nautilus if you want to view the .Skype directory (control+h will show hidden folders in Nautilus)

Comment: Yes, I got the username but how should I get my password?

Comment: Not from your own system. You need a password reset website.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to go to any website. Can I get it by using some command or some encryption/decryption techniques. There must be some way to it. Can you please help me out from this issue? Thanks for the help you provided to me till now. You really saved my life today.

Comment: I do not know of a method... maybe someone else will :D